# Is it possible on every page refresh to refresh only #content div?

Tags: jquery, html, refresh

I would like to ask if is it possible to 'prevent' refreshing page and refresh only content div, without reloading sidebar and header (so there would not be annoying blink and page would seem more fluent).

I have already tried this, but this is only on specific div and specific situation. I want to do it for the whole site.

```
$('#thisdiv').load(document.URL +  ' #thisdiv');
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not something you can actually do. You cannot reload some specific part of the document, and ask the browser to re-render it.

What you can do is use XHR requests in Javascript to load asynchronously data into the webpage. But that's a whole other chapter of conception.

Answer (score 0):

As per [docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments), you can only update one div using `load()` method.

> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded.

---

Alternately use [`jQuery.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method and update whatever portion you need to update dynamically.

*For example :*

```
// selectors which is need to  update
let selectors = ['#con', '#con1'];

$.get(document.URL , (res) => {

   // create jQuery element reference with  html response
   $htm = $(htm);

   // iterate over seelctors, get element and update with content 
   // of element in response html
   selectors.forEach(sel => $(sel).html($(sel, $htm)));

})
```